# typeorm {onDelete: "CASCADE"} does not work

Tags: postgresql, nestjs, typeorm

I have the following entities:

```
@Entity()
export class FavoriteEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @Column({ default: null })
  name: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => UserEntity, (user) => user.favorites)
  user!: UserEntity;

  @OneToMany(() => FavoriteHomeworkEntity, (favoriteHomework) => favoriteHomework.favorite)
  favoriteHomeworks!: Array<FavoriteHomeworkEntity>;

  homeworksCount: number;

  constructor(partial: Partial<FavoriteEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}


@Entity()
export class FavoriteHomeworkEntity {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn('uuid')
  id: string;

  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: Date;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: Date;

  @DeleteDateColumn()
  deletedAt: Date;

  @ManyToOne(() => FavoriteEntity, (favorite) => favorite.favoriteHomeworks, {onDelete: "CASCADE"})
  favorite!: FavoriteEntity;

  @ManyToOne(() => HomeworkEntity, (homework) => homework.favoriteHomeworks)
  homework!: HomeworkEntity;

  constructor(partial: Partial<FavoriteHomeworkEntity>) {
    Object.assign(this, partial);
  }
}
```

I expected that when I `softRemove` `favorite` entity, I will remove all their `favoriteHomeworks` as well. Unfortunately it does not happens. Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

I expected that when I `softRemove` `favorite` entity, I will remove all their `favoriteHomeworks` as well. Unfortunately it does not happens. Can anyone explain what am I doing wrong?

Comment: Why would you think that? `softRemove/softDelete` don't actually do either, they just `DeleteDateColumn` set. That is not an actual delete so the FK CASCADE will not happen.

Comment: ahh indeed, had to use `remove` :) Thanks!